# How does Dynamic load and functional types work?

Tags: kdb

Can someone please illustrate how dynamic load and functional types work in kdb? They are types 100 and 112.

Comment: does http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/Datatypes#Function_Types help?

Answer (score 4):

Type 100 is the type of a lamba (an unnamed function) such as

```
q){x+y}[1;2]
3
q)type {x+y}
100h
```

Type 112 is the type of a function loaded from a C library, as detailed here http://code.kx.com/q/ref/filenumbers/#2-c-shared-objects

Answer (score 1):

Usually, one creates dynamic load objects using the [`2:` operator](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/filenumbers/#2-c-shared-objects), but you can also create them in C using the `dl` function.  See the ["Miscellaneous"](http://code.kx.com/q//interfaces/c-client-for-q/#miscellaneous) section in the "Interfacing with Kdb+ from C" cookbook.